# TcpListener does not receive data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

So my homework is to write a POP3 messaging software using tcp packets and im not allowed to use external libraries. I start the tcp connection when i press the Connect button and i also have a Disconnect button which stops it. I tested my server program with PuTTY and it works fine after the first connection but when i press Disconnect and Connect again it doesnt print the received data to the monitor. This problem is bothering me for ages please help. Here is my code:

Edit:
The problem was that i dont quite understand how threads work and i didnt create a new thread for each connection so i instantiated a new thread every time i created a new listener.

```
namespace POP3Server
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private TcpListener server;
        private Int32 port;
        private IPAddress ipAddress;
        private TcpClient client;
        private Logger log;
        private Thread tcpAcceptThread;
        private bool serverStarted;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            log = new Logger(txtConsole);

            serverStarted = false;
            tcpAcceptThread = new Thread(GetData);
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text);
                ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(txtIP.Text);
                server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
                server.Start();

                if (tcpAcceptThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Unstarted)
                    tcpAcceptThread.Start();

                serverStarted = true;
                log.WriteLine("Server started!");

                btnConnect.IsEnabled = false;
                btnDisconnect.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (client != null)
                    client.Close();
                server.Stop();

                log.WriteLine("Server stopped!");
                serverStarted = false;

                btnConnect.IsEnabled = true;
                btnDisconnect.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                while (serverStarted)
                {
                    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => log.WriteLine("Connected!"));

                    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                    String data = null;

                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => log.WriteLine("Received: " + data));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => log.WriteLine(ex.ToString()));
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            log.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zoltán welcome.. Consider *process* the request and *answer* with (something) after your server read loop, then put your client.Close() after that, instead of on button disconnect.. you are now creating a new server side client for every command, without terminating it.

Comment: What have you done so far to debug the problem? What did your investigation reveal? I find the question too broad, as there are many elements to the code that seem questionable, and not enough context about what _specific_ issue you need help with. That said, one of the biggest issues is that you seem to be under the mistaken impression that you can reuse a `Thread` object. You can't. If you want to dedicate a thread to each connection, you need to create a new one each time you reconnect.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I realized that i need to dig way more deeper to learn more about threads. I created a new thread for every connection as you mentioned and it fixed this problem but now it throws a SocketException in the GetData() function. Im guessing that the problem is that i closed the tcp listener from another thread and i dont know how to close it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Could you change following code

```cs
private bool serverStarted;
```

to:

```cs
private object _someLockObject = new object();
private bool _serverStarted = false;

private bool serverStarted {
get {
  lock (_someLockObject)
  {
    return _serverStarted;
  }
}
set {
  lock (_someLockObject)
  {
    _serverStarted = value;
  }
}
};
```

My first hunch is boolean property is not updated.

Comment: I did but the problem was still present. I created a new thread for each connection and it solved this problem but this led me to the next problem where it throws a SocketException when i call the server.AcceptTcpClient() function. I think the problem is that i close the tcp listener in the main thread and i dont know how to close it from a different thread.